# Arredondar coordenadas geográficas para classes com intervalos de 0.5° de latitude/longitude

Tags: r, grid, geolocalização

Eu tenho o seguinte data.frame com as coordenadas de ocorrência de uma espécie:

```
 df <- data.frame(
    especie = c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3"),
    longitude = c(-48.97376, -36.08333, -41.66931),
    latitude = c(-21.138258, -9.933333, -14.197054))
       
df

 especie longitude   latitude
     sp1 -48.97376 -21.138258
     sp2 -36.08333  -9.933333
     sp3 -41.66931 -14.197054
```

Eu preciso arredondar essas coordenadas de forma que fiquem distribuídas em classes de 0.5 graus de latitude/longitude. Por exemplo:

```
 longitude latitude
    -71.75    12.25
    -71.25    12.25
    -72.25    11.75
    -71.75    11.75
    -73.75    11.25
    -73.25    11.25
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta mas ela permaneceu fechada. A função `round_any` do pacote `plyr` vai arredondar as coordenadas da forma que vc deseja.